# ListView using custom cell factory doesn't update after items deleted

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I'm learning JavaFX and i wanted to create a cell factory which is working properly until i want to delete a row from my `ListView`:

```java
plateList.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Car>, ListCell<Car>>() {

    @Override
    public ListCell<Car> call(ListView<Car> param) {
        ListCell<Car> cell = new ListCell<Car>() {

            @Override
            protected void updateItem(Car item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (item != null) {
                    setText(item.getPlate());
                }
            }
        };
        return cell;
    }
});
```

I'm populating the `ListView` with some sample data:

```java
ObservableList<Car> sample = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
sample.add(new Car("123-abc", "opel", "corsa", 5.5));
sample.add(new Car("123-cba", "vw", "passat", 7.5));
plateList.setItems(sample);
```

Now i will see what i expect the `ListView` will be the following:

- 123-abc
- 123-cba

How ever if delete a row ex: the first row (123-abc), the `ListView` will look like this:

- 123-cba
- 123-cba

This is the delete part:

```java
@FXML
private void deleteBtnAction() {
    plateList.getItems().remove(plateList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
    ObservableList<Car> t = plateList.getItems();
    plateList.setItems(t);
}
```

If i remove the cell factory the program works as intended. 
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well formed question.

Comment: Actually the code: `ObservableList<Car> t = plateList.getItems();
    plateList.setItems(t);` should not be necessary. Changes to the `ObservableList` should get noticed by the `ListView`.  If you need to update the ListView:  Calling refresh() forces the ListView control to recreate and repopulate the cells necessary to populate the visual bounds of the control. In other words, this forces the ListView to update what it is showing to the user. This is useful in cases where the underlying data source has changed in a way that is not observed by the ListView itself.

Comment: Please can you provide me with the source code ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try changing to the following, This is required as JavaFX reuses the list cells, so the updateItem() needs to blank unused ones too when passed null

```
super.updateItem(item, empty);
if (item != null) {
   setText(item.getPlate());
} else {
   setText("");   // <== clear the now empty cell.
}
```

Full [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class JavaFxListView extends Application {

    private static class Car {
        private String plate;

        public Car(String plate, String string2, String string3, double d) {
            this.plate = plate;
        }

        public String getPlate() {
            return plate;
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage arg0) throws Exception {
        ListView<Car> plateList = new ListView<Car>();
        plateList.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Car>, ListCell<Car>>() {

            @Override
            public ListCell<Car> call(ListView<Car> param) {
                ListCell<Car> cell = new ListCell<Car>() {

                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Car item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if (item != null) {
                            setText(item.getPlate());
                        } else {
                            setText("");
                        }
                    }
                };
                return cell;
            }
        });
        Button delete = new Button("Delete");
        ObservableList<Car> sample = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        sample.add(new Car("123-abc", "opel", "corsa", 5.5));
        sample.add(new Car("123-cba", "vw", "passat", 7.5));

        delete.setOnAction((e) -> {
            plateList.getItems().remove(plateList.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem());
            ObservableList<Car> t = plateList.getItems();
            plateList.setItems(t);
        });

        plateList.setItems(sample);
        arg0.setScene(new Scene(new VBox(plateList, delete)));
        arg0.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot you are my saviour :D

Answer (score 5):

According to the Java doc of [Cell updateItem](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Cell.html#updateItem-T-boolean-) method, there is slightly different recomended usage than the accepted one:

```java
protected void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (empty || item == null) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        setText(item.toString());
    }
}
```

The difference is in the usage of parameter `empty`. But the sollution from @Adam should work correctly in major cases too.